# Accents and ñ xml problems

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to create a document XML and I have problem with some characters. I need to replace accents and letter ñ.

The output of the following code:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
var_dump($this->xml_entities_s("Relucí"));

It shows:
string 'Reduc&#237;'
```

When I try to create the XML:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$output .= $this->xml_entities_s("Relucí");
echo $output;


It shows:
string 'Reducí' 
And I want this to show:
string 'Reduc&#237;'
```

I need to show the above because there is a site that get data from my site and they asked for getting data on that way in xml with `&#237;` so that it can be parsed correctly.

```
    private function xml_entities_s($string) {
           return str_replace(array("<",">",'"',"'","&","á","Á","é","É","í","Í","ó","Ó","ú","Ú","ñ","Ñ"),
                       array("&lt;","&gt;","&quot;","&apos;","&amp;","&#225;","&#193;","&#233;","&#201;","&#237;","&#205;","&#243;","&#211;","&#250;","&#218;","&#241;","&#209;"),
                       $string);
    }
```

Could you help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to encode characters. UTF-8 supports them. Only characters with a special meaning (like `<`) need to be encoded. If you're using DOM to generate the XML it will take care of it.

If you want to generate an ASCII XML you can define that in the constructor:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');
$dom
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('div'))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('Relucí'));

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<div>Reluc&#237;</div>
```